# Calculating the total area of a Region

Tags: android, path, region

I would like to be able to know the total area covered by a region (e.g. a double integral over this said area).
I cannot find any method for that, and I wonder will I have to go pixel-by-pixel.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `RegionIterator` and sum the areas of the rectangles returned.

Reasoning: The Andriod docs imply that when boolean ops are done on regions, the result region is a new set of non-overlapping rectangles with the desired union.  In other words, `A - B`, where A and B are rectangles, may produce 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 rectangles as a result.

I have not tested, but the source at [the Android xRef site](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/ui/Region.cpp) shows that a validated region consists of rectangles with no overlaps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The region is saved as an Android Region, since I need its Op.DIFFERENCE and getBoundaryPath(). I'm not sure if I can iterate over the vertices.

Comment: So it's really a set of possibly overlapping rectangles? (The Android definition of region is strange compared to any other.)

Comment: I'm just reading into it now. If they weren't overlapping it could've been easy to just iterate over them. Maybe I'll have to use the Inclusion–exclusion principle here, though I'd much prefer a method that will not be that time consuming.

Comment: Perhaps drawing them to a dummy bitmap and counting the pixels will eventually prove to be the most efficient solution.

Comment: Counting pixels will probably be very slow. I think you can just get the rectangles from a `RegionIterator` and sum their areas.  I will try to get access to source code to check,

Comment: That'll be swell, once again - assuming they do not overlap, which will cause the algorithm to be O(2^n), n being the number of different rectangles... Thanks for you prompt help!

Comment: THe boolean operation methods are native code. I can't find them in the Android source tree.  It may be quickest to do a small test: compute the union of 2 overlapping rectangles and then count what's returned in the iterator.

Comment: I found the native code. See link in my edited post. It sure looks like a region consists of non-overlapping rectangles.  The embedded validator code tests for this condition.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, i have the same problem like your problem.

I'm not sure, if it is a "real" solution. But i post my code. The values looks ok.

```
private void calculateArea(Region region) {

        RegionIterator regionIterator = new RegionIterator(region);

        int size = 0; // amount of Rects
        float area = 0; // units of area

        Rect tmpRect= new Rect(); 

        while (regionIterator.next(tmpRect)) {
            size++;
            area += tmpRect.width() * tmpRect.height();
        }

        log.d("Rect amount=" + size);
        log.d("Area Size / units of area=" + area);
    }

}
```

My Problem is: I want to get the area size of some drawn pathes. To recognize touches on the pathes i added a Region too.